# Problema con consulta en crosstab postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Buen día, tengo una consulta en postgresql pero necesito modificar su estructura de columnas a filas:

```
select anno, SUM(total_sales) as sumas, sexo_
   from sivigila_a 
   where cod_event = 110 
   GROUP BY anno, sexo_
    ORDER  BY 1
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito convertirlo a esto pero con los totales de la suma anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no aparece la información y realmente no entiendo bien como realizar el corosstab

```
SELECT * FROM   crosstab(
   'select anno, SUM(total_sales) as sumas, sexo_
   from sivigila_a 
   where cod_event = 110 
   GROUP BY anno, sexo_
    ORDER  BY 1',$$VALUES ('F'::text), ('M'::text)$$
   )AS x (anno text, "F" text, "M" text);
```

Espero se pueda solucionar. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema con el crosstab es que es muy quisquilloso en lo que se refiere a posición de las columnas en la consulta y los tipos de datos.

Veo dos problemas en tu intento.

1. La columna de los valores a pivotar debe ir último en la lista por lo tanto `SUM(total_sales)` debe estar último en la lista del `SELECT`
2. El tipo de `sexo_`, *character(2)* según tu ejemplo, debe coincidir con la consulta de categorías y la definición de las columnas de salida, ambas son *text*.

El query final debería ser

```
SELECT * FROM   crosstab(   
  $$
  select
    anno, 
    sexo_::text,
    SUM(total_sales) as sumas
  from sivigila_a 
  where cod_event = 110 
  GROUP BY anno, sexo_
  ORDER  BY 1
  $$,
  $$
  VALUES ('F'::text), ('M'::text)
  $$
)AS x (anno text, "F" text, "M" text);
```

Que da como resultado

```
 anno |  F  | M 
------+-----+---
 2112 | 216 | 
 2113 | 259 | 
 2114 | 192 | 1
 2115 | 219 | 1
 2116 | 266 | 
 2117 | 79  | 
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno consultando he podido realizar una consulta aunque no con crosstab().

```
SELECT anno, 
SUM(CASE sexo_ WHEN 'F' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END) AS fem, 
SUM(CASE sexo_ WHEN 'M' THEN total_sales ELSE 0 END) AS masc 
FROM sivigila_a 
where cod_event = 110 
GROUP BY anno 
ORDER BY anno
```

Dando como resultado el esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque si alguien sabe como se podria realizar con cosstab() seria de gran ayuda para posteriores ejercicios. 
Gracias